# How to start IIS Express Manually

Tags: iis, iis-express

Is there a command line program or service that I can use to start IIS Express manually?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`iisexpress` program is responsible for that.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line

Comment: Please don't just paste a link, a) it rots b) its like an RTFM answer and manuals are usually not as clear as a good SO answer.

Answer (score 45):

Once you have IIS Express installed (the easiest way is through [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)), you will find the executable file in `%PROGRAMFILES%\IIS Express` (`%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\IIS Express` on x64 architectures) and its called `iisexpress.exe`.

To see all the possible command-line options, just run:

```
iisexpress /?
```

and the program detailed help will show up.

If executed without parameters, all the sites defined in the configuration file and marked to run at startup will be launched. An icon in the system tray will show which sites are running.

There are a couple of useful options once you have some sites created in the configuration file (found in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`): the `/site` and `/siteId`.

With the first one, you can launch a specific site by name:

```
iisexpress /site:SiteName
```

And with the latter, you can launch by specifying the ID:

```
iisexpress /siteId:SiteId
```

With this, if IISExpress is launched from the command-line, a list of all the requests made to the server will be shown, which can be quite useful when debugging.

Finally, a site can be launched by specifying the full directory path. IIS Express will create a virtual configuration file and launch the site (remember to quote the path if it contains spaces):

```
iisexpress /path:FullSitePath
```

This covers the basic IISExpress usage from the command line.

Answer (score 7):

From the links the others have posted, I'm not seeing an option. -- I just use powershell to kill it -- you can save this to a Stop-IisExpress.ps1 file:

```
get-process | where { $_.ProcessName -like "IISExpress" } | stop-process
```

There's no harm in it -- Visual Studio will just pop a new one up when it wants one.

Comment: To start and stop IIS express as a job from within a power shell script, this snippet might be useful, too: https://gist.github.com/drmohundro/5a131d7ff6f291a33334

Comment: The question is "_How to start IIS Express Manually?_" When started from the command line (the answer to this question) this isn't necessary. IIS Express displays `Enter 'Q' to stop IIS Express`.

Answer (score 4):

Or you simply manage it like full IIS by using Jexus Manager for IIS Express, an open source project I work on

https://jexusmanager.com

[image: Jexus Manager for IIS Express]

Start a site and the process will be launched for you.

Comment: You should probably disclose that this is your project.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324027/how-do-i-properly-disclose-reference-to-my-own-project-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 3):

There is not a program but you can make a batch file and run a command like that :

`powershell "start-process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe' -workingdirectory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\' -windowstyle Hidden"`