# Resetting IIS Express at runtime

Tags: iis-express

I have some tests that require me to restart IIS before running them. With full-blown IIS, this is as easy as running `iisreset` from `Process.start`.

The problem I have now is one of my computers is on hoary old Windows XP, so it doesn't support IIS7. I installed IIS Express, but I can't seem to figure out a way to restart IIS Express (or restart a single website) through the command line or through some sort of services.

Some questions on SO and elsewhere suggest restarting the `MsDevSvc` service, but this doesn't seem to be related to IIS Express.

**Edit:** This solution looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4777927/210780

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300755/how-to-start-iis-express-manually) help?

Comment: @StuartLC I saw that before asking. My usual workflow is to start VS, start IIS Express, run the site, and then run the tests -- as if (on other computers, with real IIS) IIS is always running. So unfortunately, no, it doesn't (because there's no way to `stop` a site that I can tell.)