# Stop IIS Express exiting automatically

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I am running Visual Studio 2013.

When I stop debugging my MVC application, IIS Express stops automatically. How can I stop this happening?

Comment: I think this is was answered better here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568762/how-can-i-prevent-visual-studio-2013-from-closing-my-iis-express-app-when-i-end

Comment: @ChristopherLehnert That answer is good, but it requires changing project settings. The answer here doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is to right click on your website and `View -> View in Browser` (or just `View in Browser` for Visual Studio 2012).

This will start the website in IIS Express and keep it running, not dependent on a debugging session being run.

Comment: The problem is that this is new behavior. You used to be able to *View in Browser* and then launch the debugger afterwards. Upon stopping the debugger the IIS Express would continue to run. In VS 2013 it instead kills IIS Express. Huge step backward.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to launch IIS Express [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300755/how-to-start-iis-express-manually). I believe you can also just detach from process in visual studio instead of stopping the debug session.

Comment: But I find that VS kills manually-launched IIS Express sessions arbitrarily (especially if my webapp is inside the same solution as another desktop application when I stop debugging the desktop application).

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2013, Go to `Tools` > `Options`

In `Debugging` menu in side list find `Edit and Continue`

Uncheck the `Enable Edit and Continue` check box

This will solve your problem